# TeamCity and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, bitbucket

We use Mercurial and BitBucket for our projects and Teamcity as the CI tool. It was working fine until early this month when Teamcity started to have an issue pulling changes from BitBucket. The error message that we've been getting is:

> certificate for bitbucket.org has unexpected fingerprint 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24
> (check hostfingerprint configuration)

Following the suggestion from here: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/05/06/bitbuckets-ssl-certificate-is-changing-for-sha-2/
I have added the below in the .ini file:

> [hostfingerprints]
>
> bitbucket.org = 46:de:34:e7:9b:18:cd:7f:ae:fd:8b:e3:bc:f4:1a:5e:38:d7:ac:24

But the problem persists.

Pulling and pushing from the build server is fine using TortoiseHg Workbench, but not using TeamCity.

Comment: Are you sure mercurial is seeing/using the file you added the fungerprint to? Can you do `hg config hostfingerprints` in the same environment that gets the error? BTW, an alternative is to set `web.cacerts` to the path of a file containing CA certificates (see `hg help config` and search for cacerts).

Comment: I have added web.cacert in the .ini file. I dropped the updated .ini file in every user account that i could find in the build server. Then I had a look at the user account that TeamCity services are using to run. Apparently they're run using LocalSystem account. So I changed it to a specific user account that has admin rights, and it works!